# i have date in form "5/7/2009 6:15:00 PM",

Tags: apache-pig

Using pig script, how to convert date in form "YYYY-MM-dd" to datetime?

i have tried below but getting error:

> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.CONCAT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

```
bill_details= FOREACH filter_bill_details GENERATE $0 AS invD_icode, $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, $2 AS invD_InvH_No, ToDate($3, ' M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa') AS invD_InvH_date,$5 AS invD_pro_icode,
$6 AS invD_pro_ucode, $7 AS invD_pro_name,  $8 AS invD_qty;

date_check= foreach bill_details generate
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(GetYear(invD_InvH_date),'-')),(CONCAT(GetMonth(invD_InvH_date),'-')),GetDay(invD_InvH_date))  AS invD_InvH_date;
```

Comment: Please format your code, as code, so people can read it.
Please try to make it clear what your actual question is.

Comment: Removed all the unclear parts. If you need something else, fix your question. And please format the code to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')` on the date object.

```
date_check= FOREACH bill_details GENERATE
                           ToString(invD_InvH_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS invD_InvH_date;
```

Alternatively, you can eliminate a step using `ToString()` directly on `ToDate()`

```
bill_details= FOREACH filter_bill_details GENERATE 
                       $0 AS invD_icode,
                       $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, 
                       $2 AS invD_InvH_No, 
                       ToString(ToDate($3, 'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa'),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS invD_InvH_date,
                       $5 AS invD_pro_icode,
                       $6 AS invD_pro_ucode, 
                       $7 AS invD_pro_name,  
                       $8 AS invD_qty;
```

Or else you need an extra `')'` at the end.First `concat` month,day and finally year with the resulting string.

```
bill_details= FOREACH filter_bill_details GENERATE 
                           $0 AS invD_icode,
                           $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, 
                           $2 AS invD_InvH_No, 
                           ToDate($3, 'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa') AS invD_InvH_date,
                           $5 AS invD_pro_icode,
                           $6 AS invD_pro_ucode, 
                           $7 AS invD_pro_name,  
                           $8 AS invD_qty;

date_check= FOREACH bill_details GENERATE
                           CONCAT(CONCAT(GetYear(invD_InvH_date),'-'),
                           CONCAT(CONCAT(GetMonth(invD_InvH_date),'-'),
                           GetDay(invD_InvH_date))) AS invD_InvH_date;
```

Comment: i have tried this but this is not working, invalid date format error